# Cannot create empty value in XML node

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am trying to append a child element to XML node

```
$rel->appendChild($domtree->createElement('title',NULL));
```

I want it to output like this

```
<title></title>
```

But I got this instead

```
<title/>
```

How to create this with an empty value ?

Comment: The person who ask the question did the same thing you want to do: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516657/how-do-i-create-an-empty-blank-simplexmlelement-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516657/how-do-i-create-an-empty-blank-simplexmlelement-in-php)

Comment: so what, i got the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly add an empty text node:

```
$title = $domtree->createElement('title');
$title->appendChild($domtree->createTextNode(''));
$rel->appendChild($title);
```

The second argument to `createElement()` is non-standard and I personally don't use it, because it can produce slightly unintuitive behaviour like this.

You should always create text nodes explicitly in my opinion. Another reason for doing this is that text nodes automatically handle escaping correctly, unlike the non-standard second argument which requires that you manually escape the text data.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here's how you can easily build your xml from array (including empty elements):

```
class Test {
    public function getTestXml()
    {
        $testElements = [
            'foo' => 'foo',
            'bar' => 'bar',
            'baz' => [
                'empty' => null,
            ],
        ];

        $xml = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $test = $this->buildXmlNodeFromArray($xml, 'test', $testElements);

        $xml->appendChild($test);

        return $xml->saveXml();
    }

    /* Here's where all the magic happens */
    private function buildXmlNodeFromArray(\DOMDocument $document, $nodeName, array $nodeElements)
    {
        $node = $document->createElement($nodeName);

        foreach ($nodeElements as $key => $value) {
            if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
                $emptyValue = $document->createTextNode('');
                $emptyElement = $document->createElement($key);
                $emptyElement->appendChild($emptyValue);

                $node->appendChild($emptyElement);
            } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                $subNode = $this->buildXmlNodeFromArray($document, $key, $value);

                $node->appendChild($subNode);
            } else {
                $node->appendChild($document->createElement($key, $value));
            }
        }

        return $node;
    }
}

$test = new Test();

echo $test->getTestXml();
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <foo>foo</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar>
    <baz>
       <empty></empty>
    </baz>
</test>
```