# add empty child to xml using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The basic situation is that I am writing a xml file and there I need an attribute named as  and there will no value in that attribute, so shows up as  whereas I want

The code is as below, this is the basic example given in php.net

```
<?php

include 'example.php';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$sxe->addAttribute('type', 'documentary');

$movie = $sxe->addChild('movie');
$movie->addChild('title', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
$movie->addChild('plot', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');

$characters = $movie->addChild('characters');
$character  = $characters->addChild('character');
$character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');

$rating = $movie->addChild('rating', '5');
$rating->addAttribute('type', 'stars');

$movie->addChild('test');

echo $sxe->asXML();

?>
```

The result of this is

```
        <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<movies type="documentary">
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
  <characters>
   <character>
    <name>Ms. Coder</name>
    <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
   </character>
   <character>
    <name>Mr. Coder</name>
    <actor>El Act&#xD3;r</actor>
   </character>
  </characters>
  <plot>
   So, this language. It's like, a programming language. Or is it a
   scripting language? All is revealed in this thrilling horror spoof
   of a documentary.
  </plot>
  <great-lines>
   <line>PHP solves all my web problems</line>
  </great-lines>
  <rating type="thumbs">7</rating>
  <rating type="stars">5</rating>
 </movie>
<movie><title>PHP2: More Parser Stories</title><plot>This is all about the people who make it work.</plot><characters><character><name>Mr. Parser</name><actor>John Doe</actor></character></characters><rating type="stars">5</rating><test/></movie></movies>
```

But I need it to be

```
        <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<movies type="documentary">
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
  <characters>
   <character>
    <name>Ms. Coder</name>
    <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
   </character>
   <character>
    <name>Mr. Coder</name>
    <actor>El Act&#xD3;r</actor>
   </character>
  </characters>
  <plot>
   So, this language. It's like, a programming language. Or is it a
   scripting language? All is revealed in this thrilling horror spoof
   of a documentary.
  </plot>
  <great-lines>
   <line>PHP solves all my web problems</line>
  </great-lines>
  <rating type="thumbs">7</rating>
  <rating type="stars">5</rating>
 </movie>
<movie><title>PHP2: More Parser Stories</title><plot>This is all about the people who make it work.</plot><characters><character><name>Mr. Parser</name><actor>John Doe</actor></character></characters><rating type="stars">5</rating>**<test></test>**</movie></movies>
```

I have seen many other questions but they are using DomDocument, I am new to xml so unable to figure out how I can do the same in my code.
The references that I have seen are
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503624/cannot-create-empty-value-in-xml-node)

[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516657/how-do-i-create-an-empty-blank-simplexmlelement-in-php)

I am totally stuck !!

Comment: Wait, what is the difference? Could you point it out?

Comment: A much smaller example would have been more appropriate for this question. You really only need `<document></document>` as your starting point, and then the difference in output would be far more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need an empty node like `<node></node>` do this:

```
 $child = $sxe->addChild('test');
 $child[0] = '';
```

Now the node is empty but shows up like `<text></text>`;

```
 print htmlentities($sxe->asXML());
```

Comment: Thanks, this did worked. Although a hack but works as required, Thanks again, you saved a lot of my time.

Comment: Oh, well that's neat, if a little weird. Apparently, `$sxe->addChild('test', '');` works as well, and behaves differently from `$sxe->addChild('test');` or `$sxe->addChild('test', null);`

Comment: @IMSoP On PHP 5.5.9 `$sxe->addChild('test', '');` it does produce `<test/>`, tested it and checked the result with `$sxe->asXML()`. Maybe it depends on PHP version. But `simpleXML` is wired enuff, if you dont know how it works ;-)

Comment: @IMSoP, both the above create <test/> and before asking this question here, I tried that it is only if you give a space there, it creates a space in the result.

Comment: Hm, I'd like to retract my upvote from this, because **I don't think this method can be relied on**. I just tested a few variants here https://3v4l.org/NloNC and the code above is indeed the only one that gives the desired format; but I ran the same code locally, and `->addChild('test', '')` *also* produces that form. That suggests that different setups will behave differently, and some may produce `<test/>` for the code above as well. I wouldn't want to rely on it without some documented reason for it to act this way.

Answer (score 2):

In XML, `<test></test>` and `<test/>` are entirely equivalent. As far as I know, processors are free to rewrite one to the other at will.

As such, the operation for choosing between them doesn't happen when you're manipulating the tree representation of the document, but when you're writing it out to a string.

SimpleXML doesn't currently support flags when saving XML using `->asXML()`, but the DOM equivalent (`->save()` or `->saveXML()`) does. Luckily, DOM and SimpleXML use the same internal representation so you can convert from one to the other with no performance penalty.

The flag you want is listed on http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php:

> LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG
>   Expand empty tags (e.g. `<br/>` to `<br></br>`)

To use it, you would write:

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($sxe);
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Although you might be able to trick the XML library into creating a tree structure which it serializes as `<test></test>` by default (such as a zero-length text node), this could easily be broken by a new version of the library optimising away your trick. The difference will also disappear if you ever save the XML as a string and parse it again.

Comment: Yes sir you are correct that both are same, but actually this a explicit requirement by the client, also will have to try the other solution.
But another solution, which although I know is a hack solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

For those that are using

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
```

instead of SimpleXML, @JustOnUnderMillions answer gave me 
**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in ...**

I found that setting 'nodeValue' of the object worked for me:

```
$child = $parent->appendChild($dom->createElement('test')); 
$child->nodeValue = '';
```